# Getting c# and c++ to play nice together

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows-installer

I have a c# solution that accesses a c++ project through COM. The project has to be targeted to a specific processor, in this case x64. I am using the Windows installer to install the application.

The first problem I ran into was the c++ dll was not being registered properly when installed, and the program couldn't access it. I solved this by adding the c++ project to the solution.

For a while this worked, and everything installed properly, but then I started getting the following warning when I tried to build:

> The target version of the .NET Framework in the project does not match the .NET Framework launch condition version '.NET Framework 3.5'. Update the version of the .NET Framework launch condition to match the target version of the.NET Framework in the Advanced Compile Options Dialog Box (VB) or the Application Page (C#, F#).

The setup would not install if I tried ignoring the warning. After some searching, I found that the c++ project was building in .NET 4.0, while my solution used .NET 3.5. I tried changing my solution to 4.0, but for some reason it stopped working, so I changed the c++ to 3.5.

This worked for a couple of builds, but then I began getting the following errors:

```
Error: LNK1104 cannot open file 'mfc90.dll'.
```

I added the file to the Additional Dependencies section, but then another link error occured (mfcs90.dll) and when adding that one, I got an x86 x64 conflict.

I'm not sure why these solutions worked for a while and then stopped, and I can't seem to find a resolution at any step that works. If anyone has seen anything similar to this, the insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to include the Microsoft runtime dlls, you should not simply include the dll in your application directory. This won't help when the dlls have various dependencies and you might run into different conflicts and versioning issues.

The way I would recommend installing the runtime dlls for you application is to include the official merge module in your MSI.

See the following link for your options to redistribute the runtime library:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235316(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did spend some time trying to make a merge module in the c++ code, but I was unsuccessful. This was a while ago, so I don't remember the specific errors I got. I did not try a merge module in the c# code, however. I wonder if that might have a better result?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure what you mean by "making a merge module in the code". The merge module is for the installation, not for the code. And you should not create a new merge module, you should download the official Visual C++ Runtime merge module(s) from Microsoft and include those in your MSI.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but I am new to C++. The code I am using is open source. Are you saying I should add the merge module and create an installer in the C++ project, and then add the msi to the c# installer. Again, thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @Tim - I recommend you take a step back and spend some time learning more about Microsoft installation packages and Visual Studio installation projects. (For example, an MSI is an installation package. It'd doesn't makes sense to "add the msi to the c# installer".)

Comment: @Cyborgx37 - Thank you for the comment; I fully admit that I need to learn more about installers. I do know that the msi is the installer, but I want a single installer to install both the c++ and c# code, which is why I was asking about adding the c++ msi to the c# installer.

Comment: I added the merge module, and was able to once again build the installer. Thank you for your help, Ran.

Comment: @Tim - Glad to see you got things working. An installation project is pretty much language/platform agnostic (that's why it's a separate project). You should be able to point the installation project to your other projects. It will automatically detect the output of those project (depending on how you've configured them). You can then configure how that output is installed onto a target machine. The output of the installation project is a final, complete MSI (or setup.exe). You should not generally need to add a completed installation package to another installation package.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 - Thank you for the tip. Before starting this job I had never created an installer before. I was put on several small projects, so have had to muddle my way through following online tutorials that say what to do, but do not spend time on the theory behind the actions. When I get some free time, I need to sit down with a book or a more detailed website and figure out the nuances. When I get some free time... Thank you all for your assistance.